# How to loop a plot combination to remaining variables in dataframe

Tags: r, function, loops, plot

***What I want to do***

I have a plot, where there is x = a categorial variable (Country) and y = a numeric variable (Response). I want to loop the code, so that all remaining numeric variables (pls. se my example df below) also are plotted with the same x = categorial variable, without having to recreate the same piece of code each time.

**What I have tried to do/planned out**

I have my code for the plot that I want to loop. I have set this a being a function, as I want to use the same code, though with different y-values each time.

```
par(mfrow(c = 2,3)) 

fun_1 <- function (x)

  x <- small_df %>%
  ggplot(aes(Country, Response, color = Country))+
  geom_point() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
```

I then thought that the next step, would be to make a for-loop, and already here my competencies in R fall short. I have an idea what needs to be in the for loop, but I haven't been able to figure how to even really start on the coding process it self.

My dataframe har 7 rows and 5 variables.

*How I imagine the loop is to be structured is as the following:*

```
for(i in 1:7) { ## loop for each row in df

 Where X = Country is constant for each loop
 Loop the function for all the remaining Y (BNP_USD, Currency, BirthRate)
 Print out a plot for each X and Y combination 

}
```

Print plots

***Example of simple data***

Imagine the dataframe is as the following:

```
Country <- c("BDG", "CHN", "MMR", "IDN", "IND", "LKA", "KHM")
Response <- c(30, 15, 25, 10, 11, 21, 16)
BNP_USD <- c(10000,20000,30000,40000,50000,60000,70000)
Currency <- c(0.1, 3.2, 6.02, 8.0, 7.5, 0.06, 8.8)
BirthRate <- c(4, 2, 3, 4, 2, 2, 2)

df <- data.frame(Country, Response, BNP_USD, Currency, BirthRate)
```

Expected results would be a plot across all numeric variables, that all have x = Country.

Answer (score 3):

This is a `tidyverse` option, that uses some reshaping and `facet_wrap`:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather(variable, value, -Country) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Country, value, color = variable))+
  geom_point() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))+
  facet_wrap(~variable, scales = "free")
```

[image]

You can remove the legend if you prefer.

Not sure if this your ideal output / plots, or if you prefer to have each one separately, but this is a very easy and straight-forward way to perform some data exploration.

Answer (score 2):

Easy peasy, you already done half of the job.

```
fun_1 <- function (df, var) {
  df$y <- df[,var]
  ggplot(df, aes(x=Country, y=y, color = Country))+
  geom_point() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
}

plots <- lapply(colnames(df)[-1], function(x) fun_1(df, x))
library(cowplot)
plot_grid(plotlist=plots)
```

[image]

Notes:

1. cowplot replaces your default theme by `theme_cowplot`. You can unset this with `theme_set(theme_grey)`.
2. This solution is more general than using facet_wrap, but it has the downside of not having a common legend. You can amend that by adding `theme(legend.position = "none")` to some of your plots.
3. `plot_grid` has several options that allow you to specify number of rows or width of the columns, adding labels and more. Take a look at them.
4. I am not sure whether this is the best way to choose. What do you want to show? How about coding one response variable on `x`, one on `y`, one as size of the symbols and Country as color? Also note that `Currency` and `BNP_USD` are highly correlated, so maybe you don't need them all):

[image]